# Should i use useEffect or onClick handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, react-state

I have a component with tabs say TabA and TabB. Each of them has a table who's data changes depending on which tab the user is at.

Now to get this functionality there are two approaches to it. Either i can use a onClick handler on the tab and set the data. Or on click of the tab i can set the active tab in a state and then use a useEffect to update the data.

With onClick handler

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const handleClick  =() => {
        // set active tab and setData depending upon which tab is pressed
    }
    return <>
        <TabHeader>
            <TabTitle onClick={handleClick}>TabA</TabTitle>
            <TabTitle onClick={handleClick}>TabB</TabTitle>
        </TabHeader>
        <TabContent>
            <MyTable data={data}></MyTable>
        </TabContent>
    </>
}
```

With useEffect

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // set data here
    }, [activetab])
    const handleClick  = () => {
        // set active tab
    }
    return <>
        <TabHeader>
            <TabTitle onClick={handleClick}>TabA</TabTitle>
            <TabTitle onClick={handleClick}>TabB</TabTitle>
        </TabHeader>
        <TabContent>
            <MyTable data={data}></MyTable>
        </TabContent>
    </>
}
```

I am aware of how to do it. But which one of these is a better solution?

Comment: Both approaches can work, but the better solution depends on the specific requirements of your application and the behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: I prefer option two, save the active tab on the state. But you don't need to useEffect in there, just make a conditional data assignment base on active tab state.

Comment: @Stefan could you please elaborate of `specific requirements`?

Comment: Where the data come from, is it already defined or need processing to prepare the data?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to just use the `onClick` handler rather than have it in `useEffect`.

With this, you can just simplify the pattern. In beta.reactjs doc, they also provide a good documentation of when to use useEffect and when not.

reference: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Comment: Thanks for that reference. My current implementation is using onClick only

Comment: In general, using useEffect for data fetching is a common and recommended pattern in React, as it allows for a separation of concerns and can help make the code more predictable and maintainable. However, it ultimately depends on the specific needs of your application and the behavior you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other functionality then you shoul use onClick handler.

useEffect will render the table with empty list. Then it will render with the dependent data.

But it totally depend on the requirement of the application.